# Report compile-time string constant

Tags: intellij-idea

Does IntelliJ support any features for interpreting the final String value for a String constant made from other constants?

As a simple example:

```
static final String HELLO = "hello";
static final String WORLD = "world";
static final String HELLO_WORLD = HELLO + " " + WORLD;
```

Could I have IntelliJ tell me that `HELLO_WORLD` will be *hello world* at compile-time without having to run and debug the app?

Obviously that is a trivial example, but there are other String constants made from many other strings that can be more difficult to determine with visual inspection.

Comment: this is most likely an extremely poor example as it is completely contrived; if there are so many variables in the construction of a `static final String` that you can not tell what it will be you are most likely doing it wrong. Using `String.format()` is the better way to compose with lots of variables, but that is still a `code smell` at the `static final` level in most cases as well.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, IntelliJ is a tool for reading existing code as well as writing it. I'm asking how I can use it to help me read somebody else's code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press Alt-Enter on the concatenation, select "Copy String concatenated text to the clipboard", and then paste the value into a scratch file or some other temporary location.

Comment: I tried this on my Mac (Option+Enter) and did not see any option like Copy String.

Comment: You need to put your caret on the concatenation expression (HELLO + ..."), not on "HELLO_WORLD".

Comment: Yes, placing the cursor on the expression worked. It would be nice if IntelliJ had a better solution, but this will at least let me easily put strings together.